# Global access for user's File

Tags: c#

following code implements an Access-Connection using an OpenFileDialog.
My Question:
How should I change the class in order to use this Access-Connection at each point in each formular. Unfortunatley, C# doesn't use global variables.....

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Access
{
    public class AccessConnection
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        public string Verbinden()
            {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Projects\C#\C#_GUI\ACCESS_DataGrid";
                if (Directory.Exists(path)) ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\ACCESS_DataGrid";
                else ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
                ofd.Filter = "Accesdatenbanken|*.mdb";
                string connection = "";
                if (MessageBox.Show("\tLoad Access-Database now?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " + ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else Application.Exit();
                }
                else Application.Exit();

            return connection;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to write the code in a public void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can make the class and the method "static". If, then you have one instance of the class in the whole application, like a global variable.